# Is there a way to pass only a 2d array to a function along with array size data without using a macro?

Tags: arrays, c, function, gcc, macros

I have a function for automating struct creation for my matrix struct. The struct has three properties: x-size, y-size, and a pointer to an double 2d array.

```c
typedef struct Matrix
{
    uint16_t sizeX;
    uint16_t sizeY;
    double* data;
} Matrix;
```

I also have a helper function that is used to automatically populate the fields of the struct

```c
Matrix _create_matrix(uint16_t sizeY, uint16_t sizeX, double numbers[][sizeX])
{
    double *data = calloc(sizeX*sizeY, sizeof(double));

    if(!data)
    {
        return create_empty_matrix();
    }

    memcpy(data, numbers, sizeX * sizeY * sizeof(*data));

    return (Matrix){ .sizeX = sizeX,
                     .sizeY = sizeY,
                     .data =  data }; // returns matrix object
}
```

To avoid having the enter the dimensions of the data, I use a macro that calculates the size of the matrix.

```c
#define create_matrix(data) ({ uint16_t sizeY = sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]); \
                                 uint16_t sizeX = sizeof(data)/sizeof(double)/sizeY; \
                                _create_matrix(sizeY, sizeX, data); })
```

An example of how this macro is used is shown as such.

```c
double data[3][3] = {
    {2, 0, 3},
    {1, 2, 4},     
    {5, 3, 2}
};

Matrix m1 = create_matrix(data);
```

However, I have heard macros should not really be used due to their lack of type checking among other things. Is it possible to have such a helper function in C without using a macro?

Comment: You haven't shown how you use the macro, but keep in mind that if the array has decayed to a pointer all of the calculations in it are incorrect.

Comment: Are you aware that `create_matrix` is a [statement expression](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)? I mean, if `gcc` extensions are an option you can add the `gcc` tag to the question.

Comment: Added an example @Retired Ninja. Also arrays decaying to pointers is something I hadn't thought of.

Comment: Added the gcc tag @DavidRanieri.

Comment: If you pass an array to a function, it is decayed to a pointer pointing to the address of the first element of the array and ```sizeof``` array or pointer will give you size of the pointer per se (i.e. 4 or 8 depending on being 32- or 64-bit).

Comment: I see no other way than using a macro. You cannot use a function for this, because if you pass the array to a function, then the array will decay to a pointer, so that you can no longer use `sizeof` on it.

Comment: @Tenai "and a pointer to an double 2d array" --> `double* data;` is a pointer to a `double`.  Code may use `.data` in some fashion as "2d array", yet it is still just pointer to a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The `create_matrix()`-like functions need 3 pieces of info: pointer to source data and x, y dimensions.

1. A macro can extract these 3 from `double data[3][3]`: somewhat like OP's `create_matrix(data)`
2. Without a macro, code can pass the dimensions and a pointer to the 2D object: `create_matrix_alt2(sizeX, sizeY, data)` **Preferred**
3. If the function is hard-coded for a constant dimension, that dimension is not need as an argument.
4. The function can receive info via other means than a parameter.  **Not recommended**

```
// Sneaky way to call the function with only `data`.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

size_t xsize;
size_t ysize;

typedef struct Matrix {
    size_t sizeX;
    size_t sizeY;
    double* data;
} Matrix;

void foo(double d[ysize][xsize]) {
  printf("%zu %zu %p\n", xsize, ysize, (void *) d);
}

int main(void) {
  double data[4][3] = {
      {2, 0, 3},
      {2, 0, 3},
      {1, 2, 4},
      {5, 3, 2}
  };
  ysize = sizeof data/ sizeof data[0];
  xsize = sizeof data[0] / sizeof data[0][0];
  foo(data);  // Function called with only 1 argument.
}
```

Sample output:

```
3 4 0x7ffffcb80
```